# Server Error ReferenceError: window is not defined This error happened while generating the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js, server-side-rendering

I want to add Microsoft Login Button in Next Js using material Ui but
when I add package from NPM and refresh the page I got the above
error.

When I Assign `ClientId="a973536f-eb3e-4fd9-9394-9f4194d69153"` to Microsoft component as shown below I got the above error. How to cope with this error.

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, Container, Checkbox, IconButton, FormControlLabel, TextField, Button, Link } from "@material-ui/core";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
import { loadCSS } from "fg-loadcss";
import FacebookLogin from "react-facebook-login/dist/facebook-login-render-props";
import { GoogleLogin } from "react-google-login";
import MicrosoftLogin from "react-microsoft-login";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(0),
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "center",
        height: '60vh',
    },
    background: {
        backgroundColor: "#220E1A",
        borderRadius: "5px",
        color: "white",import React from "react";


        import { Grid, Container, Checkbox, IconButton, FormControlLabel, TextField, Button, Link } from "@material-ui/core";
        
        
        import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
        
        
        import Icon from "@material-ui/core/Icon";
        import { loadCSS } from "fg-loadcss";
        import FacebookLogin from "react-facebook-login/dist/facebook-login-render-props";
        import { GoogleLogin } from "react-google-login";
        
        import MicrosoftLogin from "react-microsoft-login";
        
        
        
        
        const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
            paper: {
                marginTop: theme.spacing(0),
                display: "flex",
                flexDirection: "column",
                alignItems: "center",
                height: '60vh',
        
            },
            background: {
                backgroundColor: "#220E1A",
                borderRadius: "5px",
                color: "white",
        
            },
        
            form: {
                width: "70%", // Fix IE 11 issue.
                marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
            },
            input1: {
                background: "white",
                borderRadius: "25px",
                color: "white",
        
        
            },
            submit: {
                margin: theme.spacing(1, 0, 1),
                borderRadius: "25px",
            },
            buttonGroup: {
                borderRadius: "50px",
                margin: theme.spacing(2, 0, 2, 0),
            },
            winIcon: {
                padding: '0px',
                margin: '0px',
                width: '10px'
            }
        
        }));
        
        export default function SignIn() {
            const classes = useStyles();
        
            //Load Fonts awesome icons
            React.useEffect(() => {
                const node = loadCSS(
                    "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css",
                    document.querySelector("#font-awesome-css")
                );
        
                return () => {
                    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
                };
            }, []);
        
        
        
            //google facebook,Microsoft Login response
            const responseFacebook = (response) => {
                console.log(response);
            };
            const responseGoogle = (response) => {
                console.log(response);
            };
        
            const authHandler = (err, data) => {
                console.log(err, data);
            };
        
        
            return (
        
                <Container maxWidth="xm" className={classes.background}>
                    <div className={classes.paper}>
                        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
                            <TextField
                                className={classes.input1}
                                margin="normal"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                id="email"
                                label="Email Address"
                                name="email"
                                autoFocus
                                variant="filled"
                            />
                            <TextField
                                className={classes.input1}
                                variant="filled"
                                margin="normal"
                                required
                                fullWidth
                                name="password"
                                label="Password"
                                type="password"
                                id="password"
                                autoComplete="current-password"
                            />
        
                            <Grid
                                container
                                direction="column"
                                justify="center"
                                alignItems="center"
                            >
                                <Grid item >
                                    <FormControlLabel
                                        control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                                        label="Stay signed in"
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item>
                                    <Button
                                        type="submit"
                                        medium
                                        variant="contained"
                                        color="primary"
                                        className={classes.submit}
                                    >
                                        Sign In
                      </Button>
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid item>
                                    <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                                        Forgot password?
                      </Link>
                                </Grid>
        
                                <Grid item>
                                    <h3 align="center">Or Via</h3>{" "}
                                    <FacebookLogin
                                        appId="225241158739281"
                                        autoLoad
                                        callback={responseFacebook}
                                        render={(renderProps) => (
                                            <IconButton color="primary" onClick={renderProps.onClick}>
                                                <Icon className="fab fa-facebook" />
                                            </IconButton>
                                        )}
                                    />
                                    <GoogleLogin
                                        clientId="500452257814-peb71oi9612hv04svvfpvfrtch6pc5br.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                                        render={(renderProps) => (
                                            <IconButton
                                                onClick={renderProps.onClick} 
        
                                            >
                                                {" "}
                                                <Icon className="fab fa-google" color="primary" />
                                            </IconButton>
                                        )}
                                        buttonText="Login"
                                        onSuccess={responseGoogle}
                                        onFailure={responseGoogle}
                                        cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
                                    />
        
                                    //**Problem is here IN MicrosoftLogin when i assign Id it creates the above error.**
         
                                    <MicrosoftLogin
                                        // clientId="a973536f-eb3e-4fd9-9394-9f4194d69153"
                                        authCallback={authHandler}
                                        redirectUri="https://localhost:3000/"
                                        className={classes.winIcon}
                                        children={
                                            <IconButton>
                                                <Icon className="fab fa-windows" color="primary" />
                                            </IconButton>}
                                    />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </Container>
        
            );
        }
    },
    form: {
        width: "70%", // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    input1: {
        background: "white",
        borderRadius: "25px",
        color: "white",
    },
    submit: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1, 0, 1),
        borderRadius: "25px",
    },
    buttonGroup: {
        borderRadius: "50px",
        margin: theme.spacing(2, 0, 2, 0),
    },
    winIcon: {
        padding: '0px',
        margin: '0px',
        width: '10px'
    }
}));

export default function SignIn() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    //Load Fonts awesome icons
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const node = loadCSS(
            "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.12.0/css/all.css",
            document.querySelector("#font-awesome-css")
        );
        return () => {
            node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
        };
    }, []);

    //google facebook,Microsoft Login response
    const responseFacebook = (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    };
    const responseGoogle = (response) => {
        console.log(response);
    };

    const authHandler = (err, data) => {
        console.log(err, data);
    };

    return (
        <Container maxWidth="xm" className={classes.background}>
            <div className={classes.paper}>
                <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
                    <TextField
                        className={classes.input1}
                        margin="normal"
                        required
                        fullWidth
                        id="email"
                        label="Email Address"
                        name="email"
                        autoFocus
                        variant="filled"
                    />
                    <TextField
                        className={classes.input1}
                        variant="filled"
                        margin="normal"
                        required
                        fullWidth
                        name="password"
                        label="Password"
                        type="password"
                        id="password"
                        autoComplete="current-password"
                    />

                    <Grid
                        container
                        direction="column"
                        justify="center"
                        alignItems="center"
                    >
                        <Grid item >
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
                                label="Stay signed in"
                            />
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                            <Button
                                type="submit"
                                medium
                                variant="contained"
                                color="primary"
                                className={classes.submit}
                            >
                                Sign In
              </Button>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item>
                            <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                                Forgot password?
              </Link>
                        </Grid>

                        <Grid item>
                            <h3 align="center">Or Via</h3>{" "}
                            <FacebookLogin
                                appId="225241158739281"
                                autoLoad
                                callback={responseFacebook}
                                render={(renderProps) => (
                                    <IconButton color="primary" onClick={renderProps.onClick}>
                                        <Icon className="fab fa-facebook" />
                                    </IconButton>
                                )}
                            />
                            <GoogleLogin
                                clientId="500452257814-peb71oi9612hv04svvfpvfrtch6pc5br.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                                render={(renderProps) => (
                                    <IconButton
                                        onClick={renderProps.onClick}

                                    >
                                        {" "}
                                        <Icon className="fab fa-google" color="primary" />
                                    </IconButton>
                                )}
                                buttonText="Login"
                                onSuccess={responseGoogle}
                                onFailure={responseGoogle}
                                cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
                            />

                            //**Problem is here IN MicrosoftLogin when i assign Id it creates the above error.**

                            <MicrosoftLogin
                                // clientId="a973536f-eb3e-4fd9-9394-9f4194d69153"
                                authCallback={authHandler}
                                redirectUri="https://localhost:3000/"
                                className={classes.winIcon}
                                children={
                                    <IconButton>
                                        <Icon className="fab fa-windows" color="primary" />
                                    </IconButton>}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </form>
            </div>
        </Container>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's related to server side rendering and client side rendering.
As Next.js provides SSR, you need to consider using objects like window, localStorage and so on. While compiling client side, those objects are fine but when Nextjs compiles server side, it shows error like you shared.

It seems like GoogleLogin uses window object if you assign the client id. You need to check that first. And lemme know the result.

Comment: No actually its problem in MicrosoftLogin component when i assign ClientID the it shows this error when i remove client Id then works fine.but not able to login through Microsoft button then bcz no ClientID.

Answer (score 0):

Hey  the easy way for Material UI Components, to rendered it on Next js framework.Just use   component to render it on client side only.
(If any component use Window object on server side it will show this error)

**solution:**

```
    import NoSsr from '@material-ui/core/NoSsr';
                 <NoSsr>
                      <MicrosoftLogin
                        clientId="a973536f-eb3e-4fd9-9394-9f4194d69153"
                        authCallback={authHandler}
                        redirectUri="https://localhost:3000/"
                        className={classes.winIcon}
                        children={
                          <IconButton>
                            <Icon className="fab fa-windows" color="primary" />
                          </IconButton>
                        }
                      />
                    </NoSsr>
```